# Add user to a SharePoint group - grant permission - right groups do not show

Tags: 2010, permissions, groups, group-policy

When I try go grant permission to a user in a new web I don't get listed the custom groups on the current web.

If you look at the image you can see that the list in the background is quite a bit larger than what I got listed in the dropdown-list "add user to a sharepoint group". What's wrong?

I am also having problem that SharePoint groups which have been removed are showing in the same dropdown-list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the steps correctly to add users:

1. Click on site permissions.
2. Click on group in which user is to be added.
3. Click on 'New' in the group.
4. Add the user name.

The reason you might be seeing groups that were deleted:

You might not have removed the groups from the site. Instead, they might have been removed from various lists or library permissions.

As such, they would not have access to particular list/library but will have limited access to rest of the site. Hence, their name would come up in the site permissions